# When do comments on deleted posts show up in your comment history?

Tags: discussion, comments, election

[image]

This was a comment I made on a joke nomination (and the nomination has since been deleted). I saw it in [my activity page](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru?tab=activity&sort=comments&page=2). The HTML if it helps:

```
<tr class="" data-postid="784635">
    <td>        <div class="date">
            <div class="date_brick" title="2016-06-09 00:06:44Z">Jun<br>
9            </div>
        </div>
</td>

    <td>
comment</td>

    <td class="" id="">
                <b></b>
                        <br>
                <span class="comments">What? I thought expert sex change were going for pay for it.</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

A quick scan of my other comments indicate none were on deleted posts, and I don't recall ever seeing comments on deleted posts showing up there before.

Comment: Is this a bug, or can we just tag it as [tag:discussion] before a dev confirms it as a bug? :)

Comment: @Dawny33 sure, why not?

Comment: @Dawny33 Shadow Wizard doesn't have a bug gold badge, so that was a useful edit. :D

Comment: Actually that's a bug, I was too lazy to retag. :)